# Pretty URLs messing with my variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some code to change all spaces in my variables to dashes

```
function url($string) {
  //lower case everything
  $string = strtolower($string);

  //make alphaunermic
  $string = trim($string);

  //Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
  $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

  //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
  $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);

  return $string;
}

//some artist now becomes some-artist, some song now becomes some-song
```

Then i have a rule

```
RewriteRule ^mp3/(.*)-(.*)/?.html$ mp3.php?artist=$1&song=$2 [nc]
```

So i can have urls like

```
www.example.com/mp3/some-artist-some-song.html
```

But it is mixing up where the artist seperates from the song, if i echo out the artist on that page it will give me "some-artist-some" when the actual artist variable is only "some-artist", it seems to be thinking that the first variable is everything before the last dash when it isn't, how can i fix that?

Comment: How would you *as a human* fix that?! Is the artist "some" and the song "artist-some-song"? Or is the artist "some-artist-some" and the song "song"? If your naming scheme is ambiguous, there's hardly anything you can do.

Comment: I'd better use www.example.com/mp3/some-artist/some-song.mp3

Comment: I see other sites that just have all dashes with mutiple variables so there must be a way to do it, hmm.

Comment: Yeah i was using that but i think all dashes is better for SEO?

Comment: If a site uses a format like this, they typically have a database where they map "some-artist-some-song" to data/site/information. They do *not* try to reverse engineer that string to extract information out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you are using a dash for 1 too many things.

You cant use it as a space replacement AND as a boundary seperator and still expect to be able to tell the difference between `some-artist : some-song`
and
`some-artist-some : song`

Other sites would not be splitting the url up to get the data but are actually using a url of some-artist-some-song to represent a single specific item which has the properties of `artist: some artist` and `song: some song`.

If you are have to split the url then the answer is to use a different character between artist and song than you do to replace the spaces. Really though this will always experience problems until you add an extra column in your database for a url that is specific to each track.

A request then comes in for mysqite.com/some-artist-some-song and you then look up some-artist-some-song in the database under the URL column. This will then give you the correct track, it doesn't matter what combination of song title and artist there is then as long as the URL is unique.

EG.

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------------+
| artist           | title            | url                    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------------+
| Some Artist      | Some Song        | some-artist-some-song  |
| Some Artist Some | Song             | some-artist-some-song2 |
| Some             | Artist Some Song | some-artist-some-song3 |
+------------------+------------------+------------------------+
```

So you can now uniquely identify which possible combination of some artist some song the user is asking for.

Comment: I only have the artist and songs in the database as two seperate columns, so if i merge these in to one column, i could edit out the boundary and just use one variable which would be the whole artist and song, that should work?

Comment: Add an extra column for url which contains a single unique url to reference each song.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
RewriteRule ^mp3/(.*)_(.*)/?.html$ mp3.php?artist=$1&song=$2 [nc]
```

This way, you can have `http://yourdomain.com/mp3/some-artist_some-song/`. I'm not sure how this compares to `some-artist/some-song` in SEO terms. Either way, you can't use a dash to replace spaces and as a separator.